# How can I prevent memory leaks in pygame.surfarray.pixels2d?

Tags: python, performance, memory-leaks, pygame, surface

I have a generator that applies a series of simple translation effects to an image `Surface`, using `pygame.surfarray.pixels2d()`. I quickly discovered, however, that, as the loop cycles, Python's memory use swells, eventually throwing a `MemoryError` and crashing.

In trying to isolate the cause, I arrived at this simple loop:

```
import pygame
testsurf = pygame.Surface((1,1))
while True:  # normally, this would be a generator.
    testarray = pygame.surfarray.pixels2d(testsurf)
    del testarray   # only necessary if the Surface is blitted.
```

Whether this code runs in a practical environment (displaying a surface with useful image content, updating displays, actually applying an effect) or as a test (running `pixels2d` and nothing else), Python's memory use grows dramatically (around 4Mb/sec and as quickly as 10Mb/sec, independently of other fluctuations) until it is unable to take up more.

The problem does not occur if I do not assign `pygame.surfarray.pixels2d(testsurf)` to a variable and if I do not alter it in any way, meaning that the only way to use the function without its memory use ballooning is to call it as-is, to no effect. Which means I can look at it, and nothing else. Even a simple value assignment, `pygame.surfarray.pixels2d(testsurf)[0,0] = 0`, caused the memory issue.

I've tried a number of different solutions:

- In a practical test, using `testarray = pygame.surfarray.array2d(testsurf)` instead of the `pixels2d` view, then applying the array back to the target surface using `pygame.pixels2d(testsurf)[...] = testarray`,
- Altering `testarray = pygame.surfarray.pixels2d(testsurf).copy()` and applying that array to the target surface, as above,
- Using `pygame.surfarray.pixels2d(testsurf)` in place of `testarray`, so that the view is never assigned to a variable.
- In each of the above, adding or removing `del testarray` has no effect.

In all cases, Python's memory use (as reported to Task Manager) grows practically non-stop until I close the program *and* close/restart IDLE, at which point the memory is released. If the loop is halted but the shell does not close or restart, the memory continues to be held.

Am I using `pixels2d` incorrectly? Is there some function I need to call that triggers garbage collection that is not taking place? Are all of the old `testarray` Objects being kept somewhere instead of being reassigned or deleted (overtly or during garbage collection)? Something, somewhere, is filling up with arrays (or some other data, I suppose), and I have no idea where or how, or what to do about it.

I'm using `Python2` and have `NumPy` installed.

== **UPDATE** ==

It looks like something somewhere is preserving references to the view:

```
from sys import getrefcount
for n in range(25):
    testarray = pygame.surfarray.pixels2d(testsurf)
    del testarray

>>> getrefcount(testsurf)
... 27
```

I also found [this](http://osdir.com/ml/python-pygame/2011-09/msg00081.html) link from years ago that ends with a message that the problem was solved for `pixels2d` as well as `pixels3d`, but here it is. My version of pygame is `1.9.2pre`; certainly not four years old.

== **UPDATE** ==

Looks like `testarray = numpy.array(testsurf.get_view())` *also* creates these phantom references, so it's not necessarily a flaw with `surfarray`, but something to do with Surfaces themselves...

Comment: Does it show the same behavior if you run it from the command line, instead of using IDLE?

Comment: @saulspatz It sure does. :C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This memory leak was corrected in the `1.9.1release` version of Pygame, or at least the Python2.7/Windows version of it. Install this version, and the problem will go away.

`1.9.2pre` was probably an experimental version of the module that never had the error patched out. It would likely be unimaginably difficult to try and fix the problem in this version, since the issue seems to be in the `Surface` module of Pygame, which (as far as I can tell), is actually in `C`. To correct it, it would require reverse-engineering the `surface.pyd` component, correcting the flaw, and then repacking it-- needless to say, unless you wrote the thing to begin with, way more work than just up(down?)grading to 1.9.1release (which, if you look at [the files on the Pygame downloads FTP link](http://pygame.org/ftp/?C=M;O=D) very closely, you'll find is actually half a year or more *newer* than 1.9.2pre). It also explains that niggly little "pre" on the end of the version number.

** -- UPDATE -- **

[Here's the issue report](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/30/memory-leak-in-surflockc), if you like this kind of thing.